# define visibility in system verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Are `defines` declared in a `sv` file visible in the next file if `-mfcu` option is not given?

With `-mfcu` option [and in verilog too], `defines` declared in one file are definitely visible to the next file.

Comment: `-mfcu` option does not mean much without stating what tool your using.

Comment: So dude, wanted to remove all negative ratings, as no question is worthy of negative rating.

Answer (score 2):

No. The default in ModelSim/Questa is **S**ingle **F**ile **C**ompilation **U**nit. The means that each file on the command line is a considered a separate compilation unit ( `include files are always part of the same compilation unit of the file that included them regardless). defines, types, functions, tasks, etc. defined in one compilation unit are not visible to another compilation unit. This is the same as C/C++ compilation and is our preferred setting.

For backward compatibility with Verilog, all Verilog files are compiled in a single compilation unit. The switch -mfcu puts both Verilog and SystemVerilog files (**M**ultiple **F**ile **C**ompilation **U**nit) in a single compilation unit.

Note that when you compile your code in separate compilation steps, each step creates a separate compilation unit. This example script creates 4 compilation units.

```
vlog -mfcu file1.sv file2.sv #compilation unit 1
vlog -mfcu file3.sv file4.sv #compilation unit 2
vlog file5.sv file6.sv       #compilation units 3 and 4
```